# 'GetRawInputDeviceList' in windows ce

Tags: c#, compact-framework

Which dll do i need to use for pInvoke 'GetRawInputDeviceList' in windows ce device application.
it is not there in coredll.dll

Comment: Are you sure that it *exists* in Windows CE? It wasn't introduced to desktop Windows until Windows XP, which I believe was after everyone stopped caring about Windows CE.

Comment: i checked in coredll but it is not there. Is there any other dll where i can try except kernel32.dll, beacuse it is not there also.

Comment: You don't just check random DLLs, you check the MSDN documentation to see if the function exists. As far as I can tell, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

`GetRawInputDeviceList` doesn't exist in Windows CE.  Never has.  The likely route to get what you want (though you've not really stated your goal) is to call [`RequestDeviceNotifications`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx) with a [device class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa447465.aspx) that corresponds to the device types you're after